# How to test double, mock or stub controller side object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I'm writing a controller test, and I wanted to verify Controller1's call_dashboard_function.

```
class Controller1 < ApplicationController 
  before_action :init_dashb

  def call_dashboard_function
     @dashb.do_something!
  end 

  def init_dashb
    @dashb ||= Dashboard.new(current_user)
  end 
end 

class Dashboard
  #... this is a facade class
end
```

Actual test:

```
  test "should do something" do 
    sign_in @user
    patch :call_dashboard_function
  end
```

The problem is I don't want to test the dashboard class, since I have a separated test for it. So I'd like to mock, stub, etc this class behavior

That would be easy if I had access from outside. But I can't see dashboard class from outside the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should `stub` it:

```
let(user) { double('user') } # if you don't need real user
# or
let(user) { create(:user) } # if you need real user

before { allow_any_instance_of(Dashboard).to receive(:current_user) { user } }
```

Comment: thanks, here is the minitest/mocha syntax  by the way, Dashboard.any_instance.stubs(:current_user).returns(user)